# ng-disabled with multiple conditions throws "unexpected end of expression" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multi-step form, which has nested views (indicated by whiskeyView).

But, I can't seem to get the "next" button to work accordingly with ng-disabled, given the conditional needed for the view (whiskeySearch or whiskeyNew).

How do I organize the conditional without getting the error posted in the title?

Or, how could this be better done from the controller?

```
<a ng-click="currentView = 3" ng-disabled="(($parent.whiskeyView === 
'whiskeySearch' && !post.whiskey) || ($parent.whiskeyView === 'whiskeyNew' 
&& whiskey.value.name || !whiskey.value.style))"  
ng-class="{active: currentView === 3}"><span>3</span> Review </a>
```

ng-disabled adds a [disabled] attribute to the div and i'm handling it within my stylesheets.

Comment: can u show some details of your controller please?

Comment: you shouldn't put business logic in template. it is hard to maintain and unreadable. create a method called `isReviewDisabled` and move the logic into it

Comment: @Bryan Chen, does ng-disabled run a "$watch" to check the value returned from the function? Or, should I setup my own $watch?

Comment: with `ng-disabled="isReviewDisabled()"` it will watch the function and call it every time on digest cycle. no manual watch is required.

Comment: Seems like the cleanest solution, @BryanChen. Want to submit an answer?

Answer (score 0):

ng-disbled won't disable ng-click event of a(link) element. so do something like this at the ng-click expression:

```
ng-click="!(($parent.whiskeyView === 'whiskeySearch' && !post.whiskey) || ($parent.whiskeyView === 'whiskeyNew' && whiskey.value.name || !whiskey.value.style)) && currentView = 3"
```

mention that you should change a different style for the disabled a(link) tag.

**for the cursor:**

**--not allowed**
in your stylesheet, add `cursor:not-allowed;` for disabled anchor tag.

**--default**
see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/GkP1ukju4FWgBeprBLwj?p=preview

Comment: it does add a disabled attribute to the a(link), which you can use to disable cursor events.

Comment: this will be some work for css.I'll make a example use bootstrap for u. wait a moment.

Comment: @NoobSter hi,update my answer and check whether it helps.